# change input value depending on select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've two arrays and they are from the same length. One array is for the articles and the other ist for the prices. The first array is going to a select option element. By selecting an article, the price from the other array should be displayed in an input field.
So if I choose the second article from the options, the second price from the price array should be loaded in the input field value.

```
<?php
 foreach($article as $art){
    $arr_artnr[]     = $art["artnr"];
    $arr_artname[]   = $art["artname"];
    $arr_price[]     = $art["price"];
  }
?>

<select name="art" id="art">
   <?php
     foreach($article as $art){
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $art["artnr"];?>"><?php echo $art["artname"] ?></option>
   <?php
     }
   ?>
</select>

<input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="" disabled="disabled" />
```

I don't have any clue how to get the array index of the selected option element and select than the index from the price array.

Comment: As the arrays are held in PHP variables you'll need to use AJAX to send the chosen value from the `select` back to PHP to be displayed in the `input`. Either that, or you can `echo` the array in to a JS variable and read it on the client side.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think he has both arrays on the same page.He just needs to get the index from first select option array and then based on that get the value from the second array and paste it in the input box. I hope a little bit jQuery needed only.

Comment: @AlivetoDie they're on the same page, but as I mentioned they're in PHP so JS can't access them. The second method I outlined in the previous comment should work fine if there's no security concerns around the data being delivered

Answer (score 1):

Here are two versions

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const art = document.getElementById("art");
  const setPrice = function() {
    var val = art.value; 
    document.getElementById("price").value=val?val.split("|")[1]:"";
  };
  art.addEventListener("change", setPrice);
  setPrice(); // initialise
})
```

```html
<select name="art" id="art">
<option value="">Please select</option>

<?php
 foreach($article as $art){
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $art["artnr"]."|". $art["price"];?>|"><?php echo $art["artname"] ?></option>
<?php }  ?>
</select>

<input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="" readonly />
```

jQuery version

```
$("#art").on("change",function() {
  var val = this.value;
  $("#price").val(val?val.split("|")[1]:"");
}).change(); // initialise
```